# Solidify completely distorting

Tags: solidify-modifier

[image]
Pic1:The donut

Pic2:Adding Solidify

Pic3:Change offset

I am doing the Donut-series and have managed to apply solidify to the icing a couple of times before without any problems.

Now Solidify creates a completely distorted image. I have searched for answers and made sure I've applied scale, as suggested, before using solidify as directed in the tutorial.

I have closed, restarted Blender and tried very meticulously every step but can't get passed this.

I must have hit a button without understanding what I've done, it worked fine the first couple of times I tried.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello I think I have uploaded now but I cannot see the result.

Comment: Hello, you need to share the link it gives you

Comment: Hi, I dropped the file in the box (in the link you shared) and the url asked before uploading. It seemed right since it uploaded, butI did not see anything added to my question. What shall I do?

Comment: you need to copy the link it gives you and paste it here  ;)

Comment: "it gives you"? I am really so sorry, and I so appreciate you haven't given up yet, but uploading my blender file was easy, as was copying the url when at my question, so I am still not sure of where to find what you need.... I'll repeat the procedure and see if it works better!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/287187/solidify-completely-distorting

Comment: Or maybe you mean the url after I uploaded? https://blend-exchange.com/b/e6SRaE1g

Answer (score 0):

Your *Solidify* is very thick because your object is very small, scale it up, apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and it will work fine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!! You are my hero :))) Yes it works fine now once I double checked the Donut instructions and realized I'd shrunk it waaaay to much..... I can not thank you enough! :)